# Multiple Records On Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have designed a single account ledger in Crystal reports and it works very well. I don’t know how to design multiple account Crystal Reports?.

The reports is designed  by  ADO.Net Dataset as follow:

```
  string sql = @"select    date=convert(varchar,date,103),name,particulars,debit,credit,narrat from ledger" +
            " where name between @name1 and @name2" +
            " and companyID=@companyID" +
            " Order by convert(datetime,date,103) asc";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyID", label1.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet7 d7 = new DataSet7();
        dap.Fill(d7, "ledger");
        CrystalMultiLdgerReports cmr = new CrystalMultiLdgerReports();
        cmr.SetDataSource(d7.Tables[0]);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cmr;
```

How to design it with Crystal Reports for displaying as query?  I mean with multiple records per page?.

Comment: mahesh, before setting the datasource put a condition that if(d7.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0) and set. May be Table is not returning any rows.

Comment: **where name between '@name1' and '@name2'** Are you sure this line in the query is correct? It seems that you should not have the single quotes in there, as you are passing parameters. Should it not be **" where name between @name1 and @name2" +** without the quotes?

Comment: @astander, You are right but it's not solve my problem it's steel display as single account. how to set it or design the reports for mulitple records that's the question and your suggestion also appreciated. thanks.

Comment: How many records does the query generate?

Comment: @Skizz, It's not fix it may be more than 10 or 100 or 1000 it's depend upon user how much records he has to be choose between the name.

Comment: @mahesh: Yes, but what do you actually get when you run that query outside of Crystal compared to what you expect to get.

Comment: @Skizz, See as far my point of view I am success to get multiple records between name I have design it at Crystal Reports Detail section and it's return the records which user can choose as per their requirement.

Comment: ...If suppose user choose ten records then all the records will display at one page. I want to set one records as per diferent page

Comment: @mahesh: in that case, the problem is probably in the design of the report and not the code you've given us. Are your fields in the correct part of the report design view?

Comment: ... for seperate name would display on another page. One On One display as per page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3183/discussion-between-mahesh-and-skizz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to create one to one records as per page for handling of multiple accounts on single page wise.

You just have to create **Group** and click/select at **New Page After** of **Common Tab** of Section Expert on **Group Footer #1:**

And You will display single records on single page between Record Selection as per above query.

Thanks.....